# For a given graph, construct shortest path tree- Python

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx, shortest-path, dijkstra

Problem scale-  I am taking OSM Road network of a city (6000 nodes and 50000 edges.)
Input - The graph is read as a netwrokx Digraph. (weighted)

For a given node r, I want to construct shortest path tree. Is there a standard Networkx function or library which can do so ? If not, How can I do this efficiently ? ( as opposed to running Dijkstra for all r-v pair)

Input in any form is highly valued!

Answer (score 0):

[This function](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.unweighted.single_source_shortest_path.html?highlight=single_source_shortest_path#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.unweighted.single_source_shortest_path) returns the shortest path, from any node to every node reachable
Here's an example of its output:

For the following (very simple) graph:

```
G = nx.path_graph(5)
```

[image]

the `single_source_shortest_path` function:

```
path_1 = nx.single_source_shortest_path(G, 1)
```

returns:

```
{1: [1], 0: [1, 0], 2: [1, 2], 3: [1, 2, 3], 4: [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Where the shortest path from node `1` to any target `T` is returned by `path_1[T]`.

There is also a networkX built-in solution to run Dijkstra for every node pair([docs](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.all_pairs_dijkstra_path.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.all_pairs_dijkstra_path)):

```
shortest_paths = dict(nx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path(G))
shortest_paths[1]
# returns {1: [1], 0: [1, 0], 2: [1, 2], 3: [1, 2, 3], 4: [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```